# How to unpack binary data in MatLab the Python way

Tags: python, matlab, file

Python has a way to read blocks of binary data and then unpack them from their original encoding into a more accessible form. For example, in some Python code I am using, I use the following code to accomplish this:

```
    with open(filename, "rb") as binary_file:
        # Read many records at once
        data = binary_file.read(number_of_records*record_size)

    fmt = "8B Q Q 2L 2L 2L 4H 4H 3H2B"
    self.data_array = np.asarray(list(struct.iter_unpack("< " + fmt, data)))
```

I'd like to know how to do this in Matlab in the same efficient way, without having to read each variable individually.

Is there something in Matlab to do this?

Comment: I think you are looking for [`memmapfile`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html)

Comment: I'll give that a try. I would not have been able to find that without your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to read the data using `fread` and then convert using `typecast`.  I'm not familiar with the format you used, but say you have a collection of integers and floats.  You can read them as one large collection of bytes and then covert.

```
fid = fopen('file.bin', 'rb');
data = fread(fid, 32, '*uint8');
ints = typecast(data(1:8), 'int32');
floats = typecast(data(9:end), 'single');
```

Comment: If I got this right, this  reads in 32 bytes, converts each of the first 8 bytes to a 8x1 array of type int, then converts each of the remaining bytes to a 24x1 array of type float. In my example, the format string tells how adjacent bytes are to be interpreted. So multiple adjacent bytes are packed - the format code "Q" treats 8 adjacent bytes as an unsigned long long in Python; "4H" refers to four sets of double bytes, converting each to an unsigned short. I don't think the method you describes allows me to treat adjacent bytes in the arbitrary way that can be described by the format string.

Comment: The reference for that is at https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html